# Pass Tuples as AnyObject in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, onedrive

Is it possible to pass Tuples as parameters to functions that take AnyObject as the parameter?

I'm using the OneDrive SDK that allows you to pass a userState Parameter which is declared as AnyObject. The function is declared as follows:

```
func getWithPath(path:String, userState: AnyObject)
```

i'd like to call this method passing in a Tuple since I want to pass multiple values with different types like so:

```
getWithPath("me/skydrive", (name: "temp", callingDate: Date(), randomValue: 2345))
```

is it possible to pass a Tuple as a parameter where an AnyObject is expected?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Answer (score 14):

Tuples are no Objects, so this won't work. However if you change `AnyObject` to `Any`, you can pass objects as well as tuples:

```
func getWithPath(path:String, userState: Any)
```

Answer (score 11):

From swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>   7
>       Generics
>
> ```
> Tuples
>
> Enumerations defined in Swift
>
> Structures defined in Swift
>
> Top-level functions defined in Swift
>
> Global variables defined in Swift
>
> Typealiases defined in Swift
>
> Swift-style variadics
>
> Nested types
>
> Curried functions
> ```
>
> For example, a method that takes a generic type as an argument or
>   returns a tuple will not be usable from Objective-C.

So you can not use `tuple` for `AnyObject` as there is no matched `objective c` object for tuple.Instead use `Dictionary` to pass as parameter

Use dictionary instead

`var abc:[String:AnyObject] = ["abc":123,"pqr":"not"]` you can use `AnyObject for thar`

Use this for your dictionary

```
let userState:[String:AnyObject] = ["name": "temp", "callingDate": NSDate(), "randomValue": 2345]
```

Comment: The problem is that the I don't have consistent value types for the dictionary. I have a string, a bool, a int and many more as value types. How can I overcome this barrier?

Comment: As sdk is written in `Objective C` so you can not use `tuple`.You can send `Dictionary` as parameter and make key like `state` and set this key with NSString value or NSNumber value.When you are getting to use value you can check the `class` of `dictionary` value and do appropriate action.

Comment: `tuple` is same as the `Dictionary` you can do everything with dictionary which you can do with `tuple` at toplevel

Comment: okay so I'm trying to do this...
let userState = ["name": "temp", "callingDate": Date(), "randomValue": 2345)] but swift won't allow me to do this because the value types are different i.e String, Date, Int. How can I get around this ?

Comment: Use `NSDate` instead of `Date`

Comment: but I don't think Int works as AnyObject, so I need to use NSNumber instead? Phew seems to be a long workaround...

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use `Int` in dictionary and Swift `Dictionary` will automatically convert as `NSDictionary` in objective c and all `Int` or `Bool` will automatically convert as `NSNumber` in `objective c`.You do not have to do anything.Use my solution and pass the dictionary in answer as parameter

Comment: Cool it seems to work. I also wanted to pass a closure to the function, is it possible for me to add a closure into the dictionary?

Comment: nice suggestion of using Dictionary instead of tuple where not supported.